# Embedding YouTube Live Feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to pull most recent YouTube live events feed using [YouTube API v2.0 - Retrieving Live Events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_retrieving_live_events) 
But my script doesn't seems to work. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div id="static_video"></div>

      <script> 
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $(function () {   
              $.getJSON( "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ElektraRecords/live/events?v=2&inline=true&alt=json-in-script&status=pending&orderby=published$callback=?",
            function (data) {   
                $.each(data.feed.content.entry, function(i,entry) { 
                    var videoid = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + entry.yt$videoid.$t;
                    var title = '<h1>' + entry.media$title.$t + '</h1>';
                var video = +title+ "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+ "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
                $('#static_video').html(video);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
      </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has changed with the v3 API.  Dupe here: [Can I access all live broadcasts with YouTube's LiveStreaming API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380083/can-i-access-all-live-broadcasts-with-youtubes-livestreaming-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a dependency script. Apparently, you need to include the gdata part of the API in the header of your document. See your browser's debugger and your script which I put on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NDrC/ - the API you are probably looking to embed is here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/

If you look at what the URL you are retrieving with javascript does, you see that it is a method call to a method within the gdata api:

URL: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ElektraRecords/live/events?v=2&inline=true&alt=json-in-script&status=pending&orderby=published$callback=?`

which returns

`gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns$app":"http://www.w3...`

and is executed as javascript. Therefore a method called gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded must be provided for the execution to succeed.

A workaround explaining how to fake a gdata.io.handledScriptLoaded method to just extract the data is shown here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-en/83Kpr9oSxFM