# Can I access all live broadcasts with YouTube's LiveStreaming API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Meerkat allows access to all its live broadcasts via REST API. Does YouTube's live streaming API allow the same? I can see that they allow CRUD through the API for a particular user. My question is can I access all live broadcasts with the API?

Comment: Hey @nkukday did my answer help?  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the streams! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Search/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint of the regular YouTube v3 API and filter the results to only receive live content.  Make sure to pass in the following parameters:

`part -> snippet`

`eventType -> live`

`type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)

The full get request:

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Does the YouTube v3 API expose an endpoint to access the .m3u8 for the live stream?

Comment: @nkukday you should ask a new question.

Comment: unable to see a manifest file in the response, even the videos endpoint.